# Kotlin error Smart cast to 'X' is impossible, because 'state' is a property that has open or custom getter when trying to observe state

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm try to observe state as you see but when i use `when` and try to get data, compiler says `Smart cast is impossible` by casting it solves the problem but It felt like i'm doing it in wrong way, i want to know there is any other solution to fix this error.

```
sealed class Response<out T : Any> {
    object Loading : Response<Nothing>()
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Response<T>()
    data class Error(val error: ResultError, val message: String? = null) : Response<Nothing>()
}
```

```
val userState by userViewModel.userState.collectAsState()
when(userState){
    is Response.Error   -> userState.error // Smart cast to 'Response.Error' is impossible, because 'userState' is a property that has open or custom getter
    Response.Loading    -> Unit
    is Response.Success -> userState.data // Smart cast to 'Response.Success<User>' is impossible, because 'userState' is a property that has open or custom getter
}
```

Comment: Can you show what `userViewModel.userState.collectAsState().getValue()` does?

Comment: @Sweeper `Type 'Response<User>' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate`

Answer (score 29):

This line:

```kotlin
val userState by userViewModel.userState.collectAsState()
```

Defines `userState` through a delegate, so the compiler cannot guarantee that subsequent reads of the property's value will give the same value. In particular here, it means the access in the `when()` condition and the access within the `when`'s branches might not return the same value from the compiler's point of view, thus it cannot smart cast.

You could use an intermediate variable here:

```kotlin
val userState by userViewModel.userState.collectAsState()
when(val s = userState){
    is Response.Error   -> s.error
    Response.Loading    -> Unit
    is Response.Success -> s.data
}
```

Now since `s` is a local `val` the compiler *can* guarantee it will have the same value in the condition and in the `when` branches, and smart casting works

Comment: great solution! The only thing is now Android Studio built in lint gives a hint that the variable can be inline, not realizing that it'll break the smart cast((

Comment: If that's still the case, it should be reported to Android Studio's development team as a bug

Answer (score 1):

Compiler can only perform smart casts when it can guarantee that the value won't change with time. Otherwise, we might get into the situation where after the type check the variable changed to another value and does no longer satisfy the previous constraint.

Delegated properties (ones declared with `by` keyword) are much different than "normal" variables. They don't really hold any value, but each time we access them, we actually invoke `getValue()` (or `setValue()`) on their delegate. With each access the delegate may provide a different value. Compiler can't guarantee immutability of the value and therefore smart casts are disallowed.

To fix this problem, we need to create a local copy of the data that is delegated. This is like invoking `getValue()` and storing the result as a local variable, so it can no longer change. Then we can perform smart casts on this local data copy. It can be understood better with the following example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val delegated by Delegate()

    println(delegated) // 0
    println(delegated) // 1
    println(delegated) // 2

    val local = delegated // `local` set to 3

    println(local) // 3
    println(delegated) // 4
    println(local) // 3
}

class Delegate {
    var i = 0

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int {
        return i++
    }
}
```

Each time we access `delegated` it returns a different value. It may change between `null` and not null or even change the type entirely. When we assign it to `local` we take "current" value of `delegated` and store its copy locally. Then `delegated` still changes with each access, but `local` is constant, so we can perform smart casts on it.

Depending on your case, if there is a way to acquire "current" or "direct" value of `userViewModel.userState.collectAsState()` then you can use it when assigning to `userState` - then it should work as you expect. If there is no such function, then I think the easiest is to use another variable to store a local copy, like this:

```kotlin
val _userState by userViewModel.userState.collectAsState() // delegated
val userState = _userState // local copy, immutable
when(userState){
    is Response.Error   -> userState.error // Smart cast to 'Response.Error' is impossible, because 'userState' is a property that has open or custom getter
    Response.Loading    -> Unit
    is Response.Success -> userState.data // Smart cast to 'Response.Success<User>' is impossible, because 'userState' is a property that has open or custom getter
}
```

Comment: `we need to copy the value to the local scope instead of delegating it`  i'm little bit confused can you explain it please with code

Comment: See updated answer. Note I didn't put new content at the end, because this way I think it is easier to understand. You need to re-read it starting from the second paragraph. @KunalSharma

Comment: but in this case stupid compiler shows warning `Variable is same as ***' and can be inlined`, so annoying

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few examples where there is too much "magic".

Doing this without the delegate property (`by`) works as expected, allowing smart cast to work:

```
val userState = userViewModel.userState.collectAsState().value
when(userState){
    is Response.Error   -> userState.error
    Response.Loading    -> Unit
    is Response.Success -> userState.data
}
```

I think this is what Sweeper meant on the comments to the original question.